# AngularJS - Scrolling within two containers - anchorScroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page with two columns of a fixed height. The items in each column are ng-repeated.

How can I scroll within each column to a certain id? is that possible with AngularJS?

[image: example]

Code

```
<div>
  Scroll to a position
  Column #: <input style="width: 20px;">  
  Item #: <input style="width: 20px;">
</div>

<div class='column'>Column one
  <div id="col-1-{{$index}}" class='item' ng-repeat='item in itemsOne track by $index'>
    {{$index}} ..... {{item}}
  </div> 
</div>
<div class='column'>Column two
  <div id="col-2-{{$index}}" class='item' ng-repeat='item in itemsTwo track by $index'>
    {{$index}} ..... {{item}}
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.controller( 'myCtrl', [ '$scope', function ( $scope ){

  $scope.value = 'test';
  $scope.itemsOne = [];
  $scope.itemsTwo = [];

  for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
    $scope.itemsOne.push(makeSentence());
    $scope.itemsTwo.push(makeSentence());
  }

  function makeSentence() {
    var text = ""; 
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < Math.random() * 200; i++ ){
      for( var i=0; i < Math.random() * possible.length; i++ )
          text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
      text += " ";
    }
    //console.log(text);
    return text;
  }

  $scope.scrollMeTo = function(column, row){
    // scroll me to an area in a column
  };

}] );
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/WYtntRagJdQoK7k6fAPc?p=preview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I changed your plunkr to make it work, there is room for a lot of improvement, but please take notice that when you need to handle things in the DOM, you must always do that using directives, as the one I made:

```
app.directive('autoScrollTo', function () {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.autoScrollTo, function(value) {
      if (value) {
        var pos = $("#" +attrs.prefixId +value, $(element)).position().top + $(element).scrollTop() - $(element).position().top;
        $(element).animate({
            scrollTop : pos
        }, 1000);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

See it running: http://plnkr.co/edit/2gb8ZdZ5DPanRBVQvTwa?p=preview

Hope that helps.

Comment: Awesome answer, works exactly like I hoped, thanks so much man. I was hoping to do this with something like anchorScroll, but this works great as well.